# Obtener la fecha de hoy con datepicker de jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

¿Cómo puede obtener la fecha actual preseleccionada, con [.datepicker()](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Éste es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

Seleccionar fecha:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: ¿Y si aceptas la respuesta? :D

Answer (score 5):

Solo tienes que llamar al método [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) después de inicializarlo:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Acá un ejemplo:

```js
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="datepicker">Selecciona Fecha:</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
</div>
```

Y acá otro ejemplo asignándole otra fecha:

```js
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1
    }).datepicker("setDate", "19/09/2016");
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="datepicker">Selecciona Fecha:</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @EGR33 de nada! Si te sirvió no olvides votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada al lado izquierdo de la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo uso moment para conocer la fecha actual.

Despues es solo asignar la fecha usando

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', now.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Aqui el ejemplo completo

```js
$(function () {
  
  var now = moment();
  
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
  
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });
  
  $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', now.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Selecciona Fecha:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario usar todo una librería (`moment.js`) solo para sacar el día actual? El formato ya está definido en el datepicker.

Comment: @César me parecio que era la forma mas simple de trabajar con fechas, usando el Date de javascript queda algo rebuscado el codigo. Hay que darle formato a la fecha porque el setDate no reconoce el objeto now de monent